# Can someone identify what berry this is?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, berries

I have a very tall tree in my backyard (Long Island, NY) about 10-12 feet (3.5-4m) tall. It has all these black berries on the branches.

However, my understanding is blackberries do not grow on trees. Any help identifying would be appreciated. There's so many I would love to eat them if I could.

[image: Blackberry-like fruit]

Comment: I'm struggling to make "10-12 feet tall" and "a very tall tree" apply to the same tree. A very tall shrub, perhaps. 1/3 the size of the mulberry trees I used to grab what I could from the lower branches of, and those were not particularly tall trees. Nice clear picture of fruit and leaves, though.

Answer (score 4):

Based of the shape and color of the berry, and the shape of the slightly serrated leaves, this is likely a [Black Mulberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morus_nigra) tree.

[image]

[Source](http://www.biolib.de/)